# Android Studio java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, placeholder

I'm moving now my project from Android Studio 0.2.x to 0.3.0 and I have quite strange problem.

LoginActivity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, TextWatcher {

    private EditText _loginEditText;
    private EditText _passwordEditText;
    private Button _loginButton;

    private String _login;
    private String _password;
    private String _result;

    private ProgressDialog _progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

        _loginEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEditText);
        _loginEditText.addTextChangedListener(this);

        _passwordEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);
        _passwordEditText.addTextChangedListener(this);

        _loginEditText.requestFocus();

        _loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        _loginButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        _loginEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEditText);
        _loginEditText.addTextChangedListener(this);
        _loginEditText.setText(_login);
        _loginEditText.setSelection(_loginEditText.getText().length());

        _passwordEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);
        _passwordEditText.addTextChangedListener(this);
        _passwordEditText.setText(_password);
        _passwordEditText.setSelection(_passwordEditText.getText().length());

        _loginEditText.requestFocus();

        _loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        _loginButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.loginButton: {
                //SMTH...
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (_loginEditText.getText().hashCode() == s.hashCode()) {
            _loginEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEditText);
            _login = _loginEditText.getText().toString().trim();
        } else if (_passwordEditText.getText().hashCode() == s.hashCode()) {
            _passwordEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);
            _password = _passwordEditText.getText().toString().trim();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

activity_login.xml:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

fragment_login.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/loginEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="@string/login_edittext_login" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="@string/login_edittext_password" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/login_button_login" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And my app crashes on lines:

```
_loginEditText.addTextChangedListener(this);
_passwordEditText.addTextChangedListener(this);
_loginEditText.requestFocus();
_loginButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

etc. so it looks like I couldn't access to these elements (loginEditText, passwordEditText, loginButton) from xml files.
Before AS 0.3.0 it was only one *.xml file for one Acitivity, but now on 0.3.0 it default generate two *.xml files. I know, that I could overcome this problem, removing one of *.xml file and PlaceholderFragment, but how to solve the problem with two default *.xml files?

Logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.package.projectname/com.package.projectname.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1269)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.package.projectname.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:51)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2293)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1269)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you expect the fragment is already added to the container ScrollView after
            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

But this is not a synchronized method, actually, PlaceholderFragment, as well as its children loginEditText/passwordEditText has not even been inflated, let along been added to the container view.

Comment: So in which moment should I try to access loginEditText, passwordEditText  and loginButton? How to know, that all children from fragment_login.xml are already added to the view?

Comment: It is better to move the handling of the loginEditText, passwordEditText and loginButton to the Fragment onCreateView() for handling, you can treat Fragment as a mini-Activity to define its view and functions, thus it can be re-used in different Activities later.

Comment: You can define a LoginFragment extends Fragment to move most codes over there.

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with the same problem, but I managed to get it working by:

1. Moving my views to the PlaceholderFragment then
2. Override the onStart() method and initialize the views there.
3. Use this.getActivity().findViewById() to get the IDs.

So in your case it will be something like this:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    EditText _loginEditText;
    EditText _passwordEditText;
    Button _loginButton;

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        _loginEditText = _loginEditText = (EditText) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.loginEditText);
        _loginEditText.addTextChangedListener(this);

        _passwordEditText = (EditText) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);
        _passwordEditText.addTextChangedListener(this);
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```